# JQuery not return any status like Success, Failed, Completed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Experts,

**The following function are successfully send data to the Controller.cs (server)**

```
 var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: href,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                        success: function (msg) {
                           alert("Success");
                        }
                    })
```

**but i am not able to get updated status from the following method**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult SaveData(TabMasterViewModel postData)
        {
            string message = "";
            try
            {
                TabMasterViewModel update = new TabMasterViewModel();
                update = _tabmasterService.GetSingle(r => r.colID == postData.colID);
                UpdateModel(update);
                _tabmasterService.Update(update);
                message = "Success";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                message = e.Message;
            }
            return Content(message);
        }
```

*I would like to display message when failed or success.* **this following line never execute**

```
success: function (msg) {
                           alert("Success");
                        }
```

**but my server side code is executed without any error.**

Please provide your valuable suggestions,

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of returning `ActionResult`  you should be returning `JsonResult`

For example

```
public JsonResult SaveData() {
  return Json(new {success=true, msg="Saved ok"});
}
```

then your JS

```
success: function (msg) {
                            if(msg.success)
                               alert("Success");
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `Content` result where as in JQuery you have mentioned `dataType: 'json'`. I would suggest you to either return JSON result from your controller or remove the dataType from jquery call. 
I am not sure about this, please give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Hit a breakpoint in `Firebug` on the send line of ajax script.

Hit a breakpoint in `Firebug` on the success method callback.

Hit a breakpoint in `Visual Studio` on the first line of action method.

Follow the steps to reproduce the scenario, and inspect the objects in Firebug before sending the request, continue and hit `F8` to send the request, check the `Net` tab page in firebug and see if any request was sent or not.

If it was sent, inspect the posted request.

if until now everything is ok continue the process in the server side on VS and check if everything is right.

then check the response on the Firebug and see if nothing goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing first: are you sure your url is valid? (I guess it is, since you state that the data is sent successfully).

Have you tried monitoring the ajax request to see what http status you recieve?
Anyways, .ajax also has a error callback you can use in case of the request failing all together.

An apropos: where does the return from you function go?
You have to send the reply to the output buffer for it to reach the client. Simply returning will send a null response to the client (but it shouldn't matter in this case since the .ajax success callback should trigger on request readyState 4 + status 200).