# How should i type cast my JSONResult to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a problem with JsonResult, as i am new to Json and MVC, so, i am passing JsonResult from Controller to View:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(Json(_studentService.GetAllStudents(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentApp.Models.Student>
@{
    Layout = null;
 }

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
     <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>
     </head>
     <body>
          <fieldset>
                <legend>Student</legend>
                <div class="display-label">
                     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
               </div>
          </fieldset>
          <p>
               @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.id }) |
               @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
          </p>
      </body>
</html>
```

But, in View i am getting the Exception.

Comment: Why dont u just return View(_studentService.GetAllStudents());

Comment: i was successful to remove the exception but now i am getting the  **'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<StudentApp.Models.Student>' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<StudentApp.Models.Student>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: If you are passing Ienumerable that means list try using @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].name) and so on

Comment: @NitinVarpe i got this **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<StudentApp.Models.Student>**

Comment: Right pardon me, IEnumerable cannot be indexed way. But they can be accessed item-by-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass only

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_studentService.GetAllStudents());
}
```

In view use

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked :), but i just wanted to know like if i had to use the previous scenario, mean if i want to return the result with JSON function then what i have to do, can you please tell..

Comment: Json data is returned to ajax success call.

Comment: what does that mean? please elaborate i am new to json

Comment: In todays web world, u must have knowledge of jquery ajax and how its used in mvc3 check this small example where its used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623600/jquery-not-return-any-status-like-success-failed-completed

Comment: Thanks Nitin, i was SQL developer but suddenly i have to work in front end, so now i have to face lots of trouble while working in front end.

Comment: well it shouldn't be called as troubles, rather challenges. BEST OF LUCK

Comment: Thanks and keep it up (y)